# Oxygen Generation System

Tags: iss, spacecraft, failure, oxygen, science

Is there any possible failure that OGS (oxygen generation system which ISS has) can overproduce oxygen in a spaceship? Just wondering the possibility how can spaceship explode by themselves without outside factors.

Comment: Why do you think there is a possibility that overproducing O2 can cause a spacecraft to explode by itself? Surely there is something behind this question. I'm sure an OGS could "overproduce O2" by some trivial amount so the answer to your first sentence is surely yes, but what does that have to do with blowing up? Are you asking about overpressurization or flammability or...what?

Comment: Are you trying to write a work of fiction where a space vehicle explodes, or looking at the ISS? Can you please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Overproduction of O2 is a small worry. O2 levels are constantly monitored. The OGS is current-limited in its O2 output so any increase in O2 would be very slow. A much bigger worry is accidental release of the 30% KOH electrolyte. It is highly alkaline and extremely caustic. Sprayed into the air, it could blind astronauts.